# TCP connection Socket.getInputStream()

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I created an application which establishes connection with the given port and transport data either ways. But I am having issues in reading the data from the server.

```
try{

    Socket skt = new Socket(127.98.68.11, 1111); // connecting to this to get data

    String message = "some test message";

    if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("send")){

         OutputStream outToServer = skt.getOutputStream();
          outToServer.write(message); // this is working, message stored on server-side
    }else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("receive")){
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sit.getInputStream()));

          String fromServer = in.readLine();
          System.Out.Println(fromServer);
    }

}catch(IOException io){
   io.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this program everything is working as expected. except in.readline().

I tried running this program in debugging mode, and the by the time compiler reaches this command. is was doing nothing and i can't see the cursor also

Comment: What do you expect to happen ? It sounds like your server isn't sending you a line, so debug what's happening on the server (and even on the TCP stream using e.g. Wireshark.)

Comment: Your `BufferedReader` is getting an input stream from a variable called `sit` but your `Socket` is declared with a name of `skt`. Is this a typo?

Comment: What about `equalsIgnoreCase(receive)` without quotes?

Comment: These typo errors were not in the actual code. my question is I'm not getting the stream of data or not even throwing any exception/errors. the program keeps running for hours and terminating without printing the expected stream of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you are trying to do an `in.readLine()` this requires that the server terminates the "receive" command which it is sending to the client with a newline.. "\n" or "\r\n" along

Comment: does in.read() get the full string of data? can you tell how to get the data. because whatever read/readLine the program is terminating. how to get this work??

Comment: `in.read()` will only retrieve a single character.. you need to use `in.read(char[], int, int)` method to read into an char buffer array. keep reading until you get a -1 after which you convert the buffer array to a String.. then check if this string.equalsIgnoreCase("receive")